# i can normally compile the file but when i run javac on it i get "cannot find symbol". What am i missing?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package, javac, cannot-find-symbol

i am trying to create and object ExerciseLib with the following java code, and then call a method on the object to print a list:

```
ExerciseLib entry = new ExerciseLib();
out.println(entry.getEmploees("http://ism.dmst.aueb.gr/ismgroup100/emploees.csv");
```

the ExerciseLib class is the following:

```
public class ExerciseLib {

private final String delimiter = ",";


public ExerciseLib() {

}


public List<Emploee> getEmploees(String csvURL) throws Exception {

    try {

        URL csv = new URL(csvURL);
        List<Emploee> emploees = new ArrayList<Emploee>();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csv.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] fields = inputLine.split(delimiter);
            emploees.add(new Emploee(Integer.parseInt(fields[0]), fields[1], fields[2], fields[3], Integer.parseInt(fields[4]), Double.parseDouble(fields[5])));

        }

        in.close();

        return emploees;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new Exception("Could not find csv file: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}// End of getEmploees

}// End of class
```

I can compile the file, but when i run javac on cmd I get "cannot find symbol" for ExerciseLib. I am almost100% sure that i have not made a typing error, so what is up?? I must mention that the class ExerciseLib is in a package that i do not know if and howi must import.

Comment: You must specify the classpath to the ExerciseLib class on your javac command-line

Comment: How "can you compile the file" if javac won't let it compile?

Comment: thank you for the reply James, how would i do that?

Comment: i can compile it on textpad but when i try to run it on cmd it says cannot find symbol for ExerciseLib, i cant make much sense of that either @MouseEvent